# Hide content in posts and category by id in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to hide a script in some posts and specific categories, here I leave a demonstration of what I have done but it is not working, since when using! Is_single (1001) what it does is hide all the content in it site.

**My codes:**

```
<?php
if ( !in_category(118) && !in_category(137) && !in_category(121)) {
?>
<script></script>
<?php } ?>
```

**This is what I've been doing:**

```
<?php
if ( !in_category(118) && !in_category(137) && !in_category(121) && !is_single(1001)) {
?>
<script></script>
<?php } ?>
```

For categories it does work but when I add! Is_single (1001) the script is hidden all over the site.

I hope your help, I am starting to learn php in WP.

Comment: The problem probably lies in your `is_single()` function, it would seem to always return `true` in your use. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/#more-information for possible caveats of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all your conditions looks little doubtful, cause it's comparing all the conditions when you use && instead please use || (OR) condition if you are trying to enable or disable script on those conditions.

Second: i dont think WP has function like in_category to check, but i guess you should use is_category()

Third, please add id in array if you have multiple
for example:

```
   !is_category( array( 9,12,19,30 ) );
!is_single( array( 1009,102,119,330 ) );
```

hope that will work!